# Create second AppWindow and show it

Tags: c++, uwp

I use:

```
auto c = Concurrency::create_task( Windows::UI::WindowManagement::AppWindow::TryCreateAsync());
c.then([](Windows::UI::WindowManagement::AppWindow^ aw) { aw->TryShowAsync(); });
```

But it returns HRESULT:0x80070490 Element not found.

Comment: When you used the above code snippet, can you create a secondary window successfully? Did your app crash directly or did the "Element not found" exception just a warning in the Output?

Comment: My app crashed. And I coulndt create a secondary window. Anyway, I solved this issue. But Im not sure, why its working now. I moved this code to button event from interior code of application. I think there was threads problem. I also tried add some code to give some time before second string will start, but it didn`t help. I also added a more bit code in second task:
...
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame^ f = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame();
  f->Navigate(AppName::AnotherPage::typeid);  Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::ElementCompositionPreview::SetAppWindowContent(aw, f);
...

Comment: Also the problem was with this call: "aw->TryShowAsync();"

Comment: Where did you call this `aw->TryShowAsync();` method when your app crashed? In the constructor? If it is, you need to do this in the page's Loaded event handler to create a second AppWindow.

Comment: I think the problem was because of I called this function not from UI thread

Comment: Edit: I created the task not in UI thread

Comment: Yes, based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/app-window#appwindow) of AppWindow, it mentions a main feature of AppWindow is that each instance shares the same UI processing thread from which they were created. So it needs to be called in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of I created the task(c task) not from UI thread.